# Aysnc handler for incoming messages in POCO Websocket

Tags: c++, websocket, poco, poco-libraries

I am trying to design Websocket Server using POCO libraries. I have implemented a simple class WebSocketRequestHandler: public HTTPRequestHandler which accepts connection and perform tasks and so on
The code snippet is below:

```
class WebSocketRequestHandler: public HTTPRequestHandler
// Handle a WebSocket connection.
{
public:
    WebSocketRequestHandler()
    {
    }

    void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest& request, HTTPServerResponse& response)
    {
        Application& app = Application::instance();
        try
        {
            std::cout << "Waiting for connection.." << std::endl;
            WebSocket ws(request, response);
            ws.setReceiveTimeout(Poco::Timespan(10, 0, 0, 0, 0)); 
            app.logger().information("WebSocket connection established!");
            int flags;
            int n;
            do
            {
                std::cout << "Waiting for incoming frame" << std::endl;
                n = ws.receiveFrame(buffer, sizeof(buffer), flags);
                std::cout << "Frame received" << std::endl;
                //Parse the frame sequentially and so on..
            }
}
```

I don't want sequential operation for the server. It should be async. I tried finding in POCO resources but couldn't find anything related to it. So does POCO provide async api? Like pushing the incoming messages in a queue and having a separate thread handle the messages separately while the main thread keeps on receiving messages from clients?
Or May be Something like boost asio api, registering function via async_handle(socket, func*) and handling each message in a separate thread?
Or any other better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [SocketReactor](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.9.0/Net/include/Poco/Net/SocketReactor.h#L44) for TCP, but there is no async HTTPServer, every HTTP requests is handled in its own thread, which is obtained from [ThreadPool](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.9.0/Foundation/include/Poco/ThreadPool.h#L34). While this works fine for a low request frequency, it will not scale. To scale it, you can use [NotificationQueue](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.9.0/Foundation/include/Poco/NotificationQueue.h#L34) for async notifications, or [PollSet](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.9.0/Net/include/Poco/Net/PollSet.h#L32) to react to sockets readable/writeable states - just make sure the queue or pollset are long-lived; handlers are short lived and created for every request, so you should create your processing facility in the HTTP request factory.

Note that PollSet has a [windows bug](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/2313), which was [fixed](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/commit/82c88a238cf49d483a8e0848b44458bdbf92a7b8#diff-aa51ec63dd5d1a34fab776a41c5955f8R358) for the next release.

EDIT: to clarify further, strictly speaking, HTTPServer is not sequential, because every handler uses a (pre-created) thread; it is best to do as little work as possible in the handling function and "offload" the bulk of the workload elsewhere.